# char string length and memory leak

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, char, visual-c++-6

```
int fCount = 0;
char frameNum[7];
sprintf(frameNum, %06u", fCount);


int fCount = 0;
char frameNum[6];
sprintf(frameNum, %06u", fCount);
```

Q1.  Which is correct, 6 or 7?

Q2. I am using VC6 and the file is sample.cpp.
  I think sprintf is C. Is there a better way?
  I need the char string right justified and with padded zeros.

Please don't tell me to use a newer compiler. I need to use VC6 for now.

Comment: The problem with using VC6 is that we can tell you what would be correct C++, but none of us have much of a clue what has to be done to make VC6 accept your code. It is in a world of its own.

Comment: Note that the "6" in "%06u" is the _minimum_ field width, not the exact field width. So if you change `fCount` to 1000000, you'll overflow the character buffer.

Comment: That is exactly my problem. The code was >10 years old. They were dealing with Kilobytes. Now I am dealing with Gigabytes, crazy things is happening. It does not scale well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First one is correct. There is no memory leak, by the way.

--

> I think sprintf is C. Is there a better way?

Yes. C++ way:

```
std::stringstream ss;  //#include <sstream>
ss << fCount;
std::string frameNum = ss.str();
```

Comment: +1 for a correct answer.  VC6 is older, and may require the use of a strstream instead.

Comment: It should be noted that while there is no memory leak, there is potential stack corruption, which can cause pretty much anything to happen.

Answer (score 0):

7, as sprintf will append a null byte '\0' to the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Neither will be a memory leak - the data is on the stack!

Comment: Will using 6 instead of 7 create a problem?  Take it to the extreme, will using a 4 or 5 create a problem? Sorry I am not good enough to tell the difference between a heap and a stack. I need to read up on that.

Answer (score 0):

> Q1. Which is correct, 6 or 7?

Neither. The 6 in the format string is a *minimum* width, so 7 characters will not be enough if `fCount >= 1000000`. The smallest size that won't overflow for any input is `std::numeric_limits<int>::digits10 + 2` (to allow for all the decimal digits, the terminating character, and the sign if the input is negative). Assuming that VC6 provides `<numeric_limits>`; otherwise `sizeof(int)*3 + 2` is a reasonable upper bound. If you want to be sure, call `snprintf` and check the return value.

> Q2. I am using VC6 and the file is sample.cpp.
>   I think sprintf is C. Is there a better way? I need the char string right justified and with padded zeros.

In most cases you're better off using C++ strings and streams, which manage their own memory and won't overflow unless you do something very strange.

```
std::ostringstream s;
s << setw(6) << setfill('0') << fCount;
std::string frameNum = s.str();
```

I'm fairly sure VC6 supports these, but it's been over a decade since I had the misfortune to battle with that compiler, and I've done my best to forget exactly how limited it was. I know you asked me not to, but I will say: use a newer compiler. The language has changed a lot in the last 15 years.